# How to access individual subtables from my list

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I have some code that takes a large dataframe and creates subtables for the next 3 rows after the Action column = 'BUY'

This is it:

```
    ### create dataframe from .csv
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')

    ### remove the leading rows that lack an action or MA
    df2 = df2.iloc[k:]

    ### what criteria are we creating the tables
    desired_action = "BUY"

    ### how many rows should this table include
    eval_len = 3

    ### code to create the subtables
    out = [window for window in df2.rolling(window=eval_len) 
           if len(window) == eval_len and window['Action'].iloc[0] == desired_action]

    pprint(out)
```

it outputs a very long list like this:

```
     [Current_Time    Price  Moving_Average Action  
0 00:52:44  27.9125        27.94560    BUY  
1 00:52:44  27.9075        27.93925    BUY  
2 00:52:44  28.0225        27.95313   SELL,  
...  
     Current_Time    Price  Moving_Average Action  
858     00:52:44  27.9075        27.93925    BUY  
859     00:52:44  28.0225        27.95313   SELL  
860     00:52:44  28.1300        27.98261   SELL]
```

**My problem** is that I would like to access the individual data points in each one of these lists like the price and moving average. Is there a way to turn this into many different dataframes where I could access the data from there? (seems like it would be a bad idea, performance-wise) Maybe create different lists within each subtable?

Comment: The question is what do you want to do with individual sub dataframe?

Comment: I'm trying to get the price and moving average from each sub dataframe. Like, I would like to get the first, second, and third price from each subdataframe to perform math on it. Something similar like subtable1['Price'][1] - subtable1['Price'][0] = 27.9075-27.9125.